# Get city name from GMSPlace

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm trying to get city name from GMSPlace on autocomplete over this method 

`- (void)viewController:(GMSAutocompleteViewController *)viewController
didAutocompleteWithPlace:(GMSPlace *)place { }`

Answer (score 1):

first of all `GMSPlace` don't have a city property but I think that maybe using a workAround we could solve your problem, maybe using the geocoder with the `coordinate` property

```
- (void)viewController:(GMSAutocompleteViewController *)viewController
didAutocompleteWithPlace:(GMSPlace *)place 
{
      [[GMSGeocoder geocoder] reverseGeocodeCoordinate:[place coordinate] completionHandler:
     ^(GMSReverseGeocodeResponse *response, NSError *error){
         if(error)
         {
             failed(error);
             return;
         }

         NSString * city = [response.firstResult locality];               
     }];
}
```

I hope this helps you, best regards

Answer (score -1):

```
-(BOOL)viewController:(GMSAutocompleteViewController *)viewController didSelectPrediction:(GMSAutocompletePrediction *)prediction{
    return  YES;
}

-(void)viewController:(GMSAutocompleteViewController *)viewController didAutocompleteWithPlace:(GMSPlace *)place{


    addressStr = place.formattedAddress;

    CGFloat lat = place.coordinate.latitude;
    CGFloat longitudeVal = place.coordinate.longitude;

    latStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",lat];
    lngStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",longitudeVal];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    [_rentParkingTableView reloadData];

}

-(void)viewController:(GMSAutocompleteViewController *)viewController didFailAutocompleteWithError:(NSError *)error{

}

-(void)wasCancelled:(GMSAutocompleteViewController *)viewController{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```